# Error "Unable to access jarfile" after execute script .sh in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, path

I have a problem when executing my servidor.sh. It contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running..."
java -jar $HOME/servidor.jar
```

I execute servidor.sh and the result is:

```
alumno@uned:~$ sh servidor.sh
Running...
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/alumno/servidor.jar
```

I am in Ubuntu from a VirtualBox machine.
servidor.jar has permission to execute and I think it is in the correct location because I can launch it without error with java -jar servidor.jar from shell:

```
alumno@uned:~$ java -jar servidor.jar
Inicializando servicios...
 >> ServicioAutenticacion
 >> ServicioDatos
 >> ServicioGestor
```

I've tried all the solutions that are in other posts but without results.
I am crazy because I need a solution and I do not know what more can I do.

Comment: Try, "java -jar /home/alumno/servidor.jar"    OR whatever the absolute path to your servidor.jar is

Comment: I tried it but i have obtained the same eror result. After this i have tried this:

Comment: After that I have tried creating a new directory and cd to it my file servidor.sh and I have given permission with chmod 0755 $HOME/new_directory/servidor.sh and i have tried with ./servidor.sh and go perfect. Before I have created in Ubuntu servidor.sh because the first time I created it in windows and copy the file to my VirtualBox machine with a "interpreter error bash^M".

Answer (score 1):

First you need check if **dos2unix** is installed in your system, if installed then run the below command -

**dos2unix myshellfile.sh**

and it works..

If you do not have dos2unix installed, install it first.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Following steps helped me to fix it.Go to the directory where the jar file located.

```
cd /home/alumno/
```

Then execute the .jar file in the directory using,

```
java -jar ./servidor.jar
```

That worked for me.